# How to improve PDF rasterization quality in PhantomJS?

Tags: charts, printing, phantomjs, chart.js, dpi

I'm using [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) to print a webpage including several elements like text and charts (in ChartJS). Texts look fine but charts and images look noisy and pixelated. See:

[image]

Notice how the chart borders are pixelated. This must be a PhantomJS rasterize issue but don't find any setting to increase the quality of the generated PDF or the rasterization process.

I've tried:

- Increasing DPI with `page.dpi = 200;`. Doesn't seems to have any effect.
- Increasing DPI with `page.property('dpi', 200);`. Same, no effect.
- Increasing viewport size like this `page.property('viewportSize', { width: 1920, height: 1080 });`. Increases the size of the screen but quality stays the same.

This is my current script:

```
const phantom = require('phantom');
let url = "http://localhost:3000/";

phantom.create().then(function(ph) {
    ph.createPage().then(function(page) {
        page.property('viewportSize', { width: 1920, height: 1080 });
        page.property('dpi', 200); //No effect?
        page.dpi = 200; //No effect?
        page.property('paperSize', { format: 'Letter', orientation: 'portrait' });
        //page.property('zoomFactor', 3.5); //Works erratically

        page.open(url).then(function(status) {
            setTimeout(function () {
              page.render("output-" + Date.now() + ".pdf", { format: "pdf" }).then(function() {
                console.log('Page Rendered');
                ph.exit();
              });
            }, 3000); //Change timeout as required to allow sufficient time
        });
    });
});
```

## How can I increase the PDF rasterization/DPI quality?

Answer (score 1):

im not familiar with PhantomJS.

i had a similar problem and solved by setting up the width and height of the container that contains the chart

```
<div id="container" style="width: 1920px; height: 1080px;">
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

i also added an invisible image-tag without source

```
<img src="" alt="Chart" id="chartImg" style="display: none;"/>
```

and registered a plugin

```
Chart.plugins.register({
    id: 'charttoimg',
    beforeRender: function(chart, options) {
        document.getElementById('container').style.width='1920px';
        document.getElementById('container').style.height='1080px';
    },
    afterRender: function(chart, options) {
        document.getElementById('chartImg').src=chart.chart.canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        document.getElementById('container').style.width='75%';
        document.getElementById('container').style.height='';
    }
});
```

with the following method i captured the print-event to toggle image and container before and after printing

```
(function() {
    var beforePrint = function() {
        document.getElementById('container').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('chartImg').style.display='inline';
    };
    var afterPrint = function() {
        document.getElementById('chartImg').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('container').style.display='block';
    };
    if (window.matchMedia) {
        var mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia('print');
        mediaQueryList.addListener(function(mql) {
            if (mql.matches) {
                beforePrint();
            } else {
                afterPrint();
            }
        });
    }
    window.onbeforeprint = beforePrint;
    window.onafterprint = afterPrint;
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

Now in 2021 Chart.js has the parameter "devicePixelRatio" to increase the quality.
In my case, I set the value to 1.5 to get a high resolution that is also suitable for printing with PDF.

```
options:{
      devicePixelRatio: 1.5
}
```

Documentation: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.0.2/configuration/device-pixel-ratio.html